# 'clarinet integrate' quickly fails and nothing is logged to console?

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Following https://docs.hiro.so/smart-contracts/devnet I can't get the command `clarinet integrate` to work. I have installed Docker on my mac and am running version 0.28.0 of clarinet. Running command within 'my-react-app/clarinet' where all clarity related files live (contracts, settings, tests, and Clarinet.toml).

My guess is it could be an issue with Docker?

Comment: Does it crash instantly or do you see it launching for while before it crashes? What's you docker version (`$ docker --version`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I downloaded my Devnet.toml file from a repo that was configured incorrectly. The configuration I needed was:

```
[network]
name = "devnet"
```

I increased the CPU and Memory in Docker as well.

There is an issue when the command attempts to spin up the stacks explorer, but I was informed that there are several existing issues with the stacks explorer from `clarinet integrate` at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the last devnet was terminated, you could have some containers running. This issue should be fixed in the next incoming release, meanwhile, you'd need to terminate this stale containers manually.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Ludo's suggestions, I'd also look into your Docker resources. The default CPU/memory allocation should allow you to get started with Clarinet, but just in case, you could alter it to see if that makes a difference. Here's my settings for your reference:

[image]

Alternatively, to tease things out, you could reuse one of the samples (eg: [hirosystems/stacks-billboard](https://github.com/hirosystems/stacks-billboard)) instead of running your project. See if the sample comes up as expected; if it does, there could be something missing in your project.